# Forward class as super class

Tags: ios, objective-c, forward-declaration

I am trying to do a static library, which uses AFNetworking. I want to distribute the library only with .a and .h files.

However, one of my classes within the library is a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`. So my previous .h file looked like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@interface MyClass : AFHTTPSessionManager

+ (MyClass *) sharedInstance;

- (void) doMagic;

@end
```

When I compiled the library and imported the .a and .h files into a new test project I got an error **"Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'AFNetworking.h' file not found"**. Thought that the solution would be to use forward class declaration and move the #import "AFNetworking.h" to the .m file like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class AFHTTPSessionManager;

@interface MyClass : AFHTTPSessionManager

+ (MyClass *) sharedInstance;

- (void) doMagic;

@end
```

Unfortunately, this approach throws an error **"Attempting to use forward class 'AFHTTPSessionManager' as superclass of 'MyClass'"**. 
As far as I understand forward class declaration you use it just to say *"hey compiler classXXX exists, but you cannot see its methods and properties"*. Therefore, I am not sure if that's the solution to my problem.

Any suggestion how to subclass from a class but not import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't subclass a class whose header is unavailable. The best you can do is to make your subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager private and instead expose a class (a subclass of NSObject, say) which acts as a facade, forwarding messages to your private class.

You can also use a protocol as the interface for your class and just expose a method which returns an `id<MyClassProtocol>`. Something like:

```
@protocol MyClassProtocol
- (void) doMagic;
@end

id<MyClassProtocol> GetSharedInstance();
```

And then have a class like this which is not exposed from your library:

```
@interface MyClass<MyClassProtocol>: AFHTTPSessionManager
// ...
@end
```

Which you can instantiate and return from GetSharedInstance.

Comment: Of course, really you should be prefixing AFHTTPSessionManager with your own name so it doesn't collide with a user of your library that might want to use a different version of that library; in this case you could just ship your prefixed AFNetworking headers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing the class here, not forward declaring it. Any class that uses your subclass should also have access to all of the public methods and variables part of the superclass without having to then also import it manually. The first error you mentioned shows that either your class is not included in the target or perhaps you are importing it wrong.

How are you including `AFNetworking`. Are you using cocoapods?
If so, try importing it this way.

```
#import <AFNetworking.h>
```

Otherwise, make sure that `AFNetworking.h` is actually part of your build target using the File Inspector Panel on the right side of Xcode.

Comment: Exactly, I use CocoaPods to include the AFNetworking into my library project. I tried to import with < > but it didn't help. See screenshot (http://ppdevelopment.cz/fileinspector.png) for the File Inspector

Comment: Yeah that all looks fine. I'm not sure what's wrong in this case.